# Microsoft.SqlServer.Management namespaces/references in distributed application?

Tags: .net, sql-server

I need to execute some large file-based .sql scripts (to create/drop databases and tables etc etc) from within my application and came across some code that negated the need to shell/exec OSQL - but this method required some additional assembly references:

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;
```

I had trouble finding these references from within Visual Studio and had to "browse..." finally finding the correct DLLs in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies.

I am now worried that users of the application will not have these references available - they do not appear in my "bin" directory.

Would it be safe to assume that anyone with access to OSQL would also have access to these DLLs - or do I have to make other plans?

Edit: I should point out that the users of this application would typically be running from a "SQL admin" role and already have access to OSQL and SSMS from their workstations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Management Objects (SMO) are available as a free download as part of the [Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Feature Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=C6C3E9EF-BA29-4A43-8D69-A2BED18FE73C&displaylang=en)

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. So -- I would have to advise that they download that package if things do not run smoothly? Or is it possible for me to "pre-package"?

Comment: @JcMalta: you would have to check Microsoft's licensing details to be sure you could redistribute.